# What is an A minor Chord played at 3rd fret?

Tags: guitar, chords

I am playing an Am shaped chord on guitar at 3rd fret but I dont know what this chord is called.

Does anyone know the name?

Comment: Just to make it super clear, can you state what fret you're playing on each string? Or you could use something like http://www.marchantpeter.co.uk/guitar-chord-diagrams.php to make a diagram. There are online tools like http://jguitar.com/chordname that will attempt to name chords for you.

Answer (score 6):

I assume you are starting with this, very common, A Minor chord shape:

[image]

If so, moving the fretted notes up *two* frets, so that your first finger is now on fret 3, rather than fret 1, gives the following chord, with the two open strings remaining unchanged:

[image]

It should be noted that, as with many chords, this chord could be described, and so named, in a number of ways. It's usually best to name a chord in the simplest way possible. This may not always have the root as the bass note. Instead the simplest description of a chord may have a different note to the root named as the bass note, as is the case here, where B is the root (of the minor triad), but the bass note is written as A, using **slash chord** notation.

If you did want the note A to be the root of this chord, you would end up with a name like **A6add9sus4** (which is, in fact, the name my notation software, Sibelius, suggested for this chord).

Sometimes the best name for a chord may be suggested by context. If, for instance, this chord were preceded by a B Minor chord in a progression, you would again definitely be thinking of this chord as Bm with a different bass note. (In other words, the chord and its name remain the same, but the bass note changes, requiring slash notation.)

Comment: I think you nailed it Bob.  I use this chord in some songs as a substitute for a Bm chord - sometimes sliding the Am shape from the Am to the Bm4/A.

Comment: One of the bands I work with uses this chord in Summertime, second half of bars one and two at least, so it could be construed to be an A chord derivative, in that context, maybe?

Answer (score 3):

The kind of chord does not change with the fret, so it's still a minor chord.  It's three semitones up from `A` (which it would be at fret 0 because of its A shape), so it's `Cm`.

Answer (score 1):

this is also a D6 chord so depending on the chords before an after it might be that. In the case of summertime the top two notes fretted are a part of the E7 chord so if played with the open top E string it replaces the E7 usually called for in that song. the fretted D string is an Fsharp which is not part of the E7 so don't know how that is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the notation Bob Bradley's answer if you omit the high E string it could also very easily be a B minor chord with its seventh added in last inversion ie B-D-F#-A with a A in the bass. (The 4/2 notation)